# SetBinding exception using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I was stuck in this exception when starting using Xamarin forms with MVVM implementation

Method not found: 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding'.
It failed at the line `var mainNav = new MainPage ()`

```cs
public static Page GetMainPage ()
{   
    RegisterTypes ();
    var mainNav = new MainPage ();

    return mainNav;
}
```

Here is my code, I have remove the unrelated codes to keep it simple. As you can see, it is very basic, and I knew I must get something very basic wrong, but just can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance....

**View**

```cs
public class MainPage :ContentPage
{
    public  MainPage ()
    {
        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel ();
        var nameEntry = new Entry ();
        nameEntry.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, "Name");

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 12,
            Padding = 20,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            Children = { nameEntry }
        };
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _name; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and reinstall Xamarin.Forms, and clean/rebuild the project? If it still doesn't work, you can also try to copy/paste your code in a new project and see if it throws the same exception.

Comment: seems to me that the InitializeComponents() (sp) call is missing...

Comment: @kenny this is for IOS, InitializeComponents() is for windows phone.

Comment: InitializeComponent() is part of Xamarin Forms too

Comment: Only if he's using XAML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your exact code in a new project (Xamarin 3.9) and it worked fine (I only tested Android).

I omitted the `RegisterTypes()` from `GetMainPage()` and implemented the BaseViewModel as follows:

```cs
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

Maybe you just need to update your Xamarin?

Comment: I found the problem is due to the form project is created by a earlier version of Xamarin, recreate everything from scratch "resolve" the issue...